# Is there a way to dynamically create feTurbulence filters?

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-filters

I am trying to create an array of objects, each with their own unique feTurbulence filters with unique attributes.
I'm generating the filters and then appending them to an existing SVG element.
The issue I'm running into is that when I try to create the filter dynamically, the tag is rendered as feturbulence and not feTurbulence. 
Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var testfilter = document.createElement('filter');
var turbulence = document.createElement("feTurbulence")
var dispMap = document.createElement('feDisplacementMap')
var filterHolder = document.getElementById("filterHolder")
testfilter.setAttribute("id", "filter1");
turbulence.setAttribute("type","fractalNoise");
turbulence.setAttribute("baseFrequency",".003");
turbulence.setAttribute("numOctaves","5");
turbulence.setAttribute("seed","8517");
testfilter.appendChild(turbulence);
dispMap.setAttribute("in", "SourceGraphic");
dispMap.setAttribute("scale", "180");
testfilter.appendChild(dispMap);
filterHolder.appendChild(testfilter);
```

I have already tried passing through feTurbulence as a variable like below but it still renders as all lowercase

```
var turbString = "feTurbulence";
var turbStringCap = turbString.substring(0,2) + turbString.charAt(2).toUpperCase() + turbString.slice(3);
var turbulence = document.createElement(""+turbStringCap+"")
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get around this or where I'm going wrong? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you must use createElementNS to create SVG elements with the SVG namespace. You can't use createElement that only creates HTML elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rewritten your code and now is working. I hope this is what you were asking.

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';

let testfilter = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'filter');
testfilter.setAttribute("id","filter1");

let turbulence =document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'feTurbulence');
turbulence.setAttributeNS(null,"type","fractalNoise");
turbulence.setAttributeNS(null,"baseFrequency",".003");
turbulence.setAttributeNS(null,"numOctaves","5");
turbulence.setAttributeNS(null,"seed","8517");

var dispMap = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'feDisplacementMap');
dispMap.setAttributeNS(null,"in", "SourceGraphic");
dispMap.setAttributeNS(null,"scale", "180");

testfilter.appendChild(turbulence);
testfilter.appendChild(dispMap);
filterHolder.appendChild(testfilter);
```

```css
#filterHolder{width:0;height:0; position:absolute;left:-10em}
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg id="filterHolder"> 
</svg>


<svg>
  <circle cx="150" cy="75" r="50" filter="url(#filter1)" />
</svg>
```